# C# events: override or register?

Tags: c#, events

Let's say you have a custom form `MyForm : Form` and want to run some custom code for the `OnLoad` event.

Are there any performance reasons to register for the `OnLoad` event and run your code in the handler method instead of overriding the `OnLoad` method in which you call the base method and run your custom code ?

Are there any pros/cons for going one or the other way ? What would you choose and why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN page [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload.aspx) this:

> The `OnLoad` method also allows derived classes to handle the event without attaching a delegate. *This is the preferred technique for handling the event in a derived class.*

(emphasis mine).

From performance standpoint, the difference is negligible here. Unless you have millions of subscribers, though.

Answer (score 3):

Overriding the `OnLoad` method allows you to run code both before and after any other handlers for the event (Which are called by `base.OnLoad(e)`, or prevent them entirely; this can sometimes be useful.

Also, I believe that it will be a tiny bit faster.